# ui-sref is not working when the page is redirected using mvc

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

when i first render the page it shows the url as `http://localhost:18841/#/flight/Payment`, this '/flight/Payment' comes when i click on link(ui-sref='flight.search')
and my payment.chstml page is in razor format when i click on submit button it redirects to payment action method an then my url is changing to `http://localhost:18841/Flight/Payment#/` and after that when i click on SearchButton it is appending like this `http://localhost:18841/Flight/Payment#/flight/search` and my ui-routing is not working, what would be the reason?
and this is my $stateProvider

```
      var appUrl = "";
  if (!_.isUndefined(document.querySelector('#hdnCentraPath')) && !_.isNull(document.querySelector('#hdnCentraPath'))) {
      appUrl =  angular.element(document.querySelector('#hdnCentraPath'))[0].value;
  }

 $stateProvider
       .state('home', { url: '/', templateUrl:  appUrl + '/Flight/Welcome' })
       .state('flight', { abstract: true, url: '/flight', templateUrl: appUrl+ '/Flight/Index' })
       .state('flight.welcome', { url: '/', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/Welcome' })
       .state('flight.search', { url: '/search', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/Search', controller: 'SearchCtrl' })
       .state('flight.result', { url: '/result', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/Result', controller: 'ResultCtrl' })
       .state('flight.flightBooking', { url: '/FlightBooking', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/FlightBooking', controller: 'FlightBookingCtrl' })
       .state('flight.payment', { url: '/Payment', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/PaymentDetails', controller: 'FlightBookingCtrl' })
       .state('flight.cart', { url: '/cart', templateUrl: appUrl + '/Flight/Cart', controller: 'FlightCartCtrl' })
```

}

Comment: Share the related code and try to replicate the issue on plunker or fiddle.

Comment: Share the code where you wrote all your states

Comment: what's that templateUrl write as you have write it? do you have write your template in a hierachy folder like this? "http/'//'/someurl/Flight/Flightbook"?

Comment: @mautrok i updated the Question, once check it

Comment: i think i have found your problem but i still don't understand your appUrl+""

Answer (score 0):

you are in `flight` state so to route to the `flight/search` state you have to write that url in your state provider, not only `/search`